# How to debug the concatenation of a SQL query in PHP?

Tags: php

There's something with my query, but I cannot manage to find what.

```
    $keys = array_keys($fields);
    $values = array_values($fields);

    $sql = "UPDATE " .$table. " SET " .implode("`, `", $keys) ."='".implode("', '", $values) . "' WHERE id={$id}";
```

And it shows as : `UPDATE users SET name`, `password'Rick is vets', 'sdfg' WHERE id=5`

But it has to show as : `UPDATE users SET name = 'Rick is vets', password='sdfg' WHERE id=5`

Comment: That is because of the way you are using the `implode()` function.

Comment: thats never going to work, you will need to loop one array to create the `name='value'` string

Comment: Alright, but how is my implode function suppose to be then?

Comment: Don't think you need to use implode function at all. Like @Dagon mentioned, you are better of looping through the arrays to create the key/value string.

Comment: `foreach($fields as $column => $value) { ` This also looks like you'll be open to SQL injections, should use parameterized queries.

Comment: Please use prepared statements/parameterized queries and stop injecting values into query strings. It's so much easier and prevents soooooooooooo many issues

Answer (score 2):

```
$setString='';

foreach($fields as $k=>$v){

$setString .=$k." = '".$v."', ";

}
$setString=rtrim($setString,', ');
```

include `$setString` in query

Comment: *"need someone to take a look over my query"* - They never said to fix it ;-)

Comment: Ok, have 10 on me then, but would be nicer to _de-complicate_ that string concatenation

Answer (score 2):

Try looping through the `$fields` array to create an update string like this:

```
$update_string='';

foreach ($fields as $key=>$value)
{
    $update_string .= $key."='$value', ";
}
```

Then remove the last comma character from the string using `rtrim()` function:

```
$update_string = rtrim($update_string, ", ");
```

Then your query becomes:

```
$sql = "UPDATE " .$table. " SET " .$update_string. " WHERE id={$id}";
```

> This is just to illustrate the concept since your code might still be
>   open to SQL injection attacks, in which case you should use prepared
>   statement.

Comment: Might be useful to put single quotes around the data values!

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes. Thanks. Updated.

Comment: Hope you dont mind, I corrected and simplified your code a bit

Comment: `$update_string='';` before the loop is a good idea to (stops php complaining) :-)